# Looping through an array to compare two values with Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement, foreach

I have a large dataset (29 columns by 19000 rows) and I want to be able to compare values on each line and print a descriptive output.

Specifically, I want to query the value in column A (@WTcall) which is effectively a pass/fail statement. If the data fails I want to print the 'fail statement' and move on to the next line, but if the data passes I want to continue describing the data.

The next questions are to determine which classification the data in columns X (@positive) and Y  (@negative) fall into:

(Ex:

If column X and column Y >= 0.6 then print "ABC"

If column X and column Y < 0.6 then print "CBA"

If column X >= 0.6 but column Y is < 0.6 print "DEF"

If column X < 0.6 but column Y is >= 0.6 print "FED"

else print "missing data". )

I have included the code that I wrote below as well as a subset of sample data.

The tests I ran before posting are commented out in the code. Briefly, if I comment out the list of 'if and elsif statements', print "@WTcall\t@positive\t@negative\n" and pipe it through a head command -  my variables appear to be pulling out the correct information.

The trouble arises in the actual comparisons as every line gets classified with the "Methylated\tMethylated\n" description. 
It's not clear to me why this is. I know I have entries where the @WTcall column should match $BadPosition (the pass/fail check). Further, if I comment out the 'if statements' again, print "@WTcall\n$BadPosition" and pipe it through sort and uniq - I only get one value for "No_WT_Concensus" and so there should be no typo there or problems matching these values.

I'm sure the issue is obvious and staring me right in the face, so I really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
die "Usage: $0 Filename\n" if @ARGV != 1;

my $file = shift;
my @line;
my @positive; 
my @negative; 
my @WTcall;
my $BadPosition = 'No_WT_Concensus';
my $i;

open my $infh, '<', $file;

while (<$infh>) {
    chomp;
    @line = split(/\t/,$_);
    $WTcall[0]=$line[0];
    $positive[0]=$line[14];
    $negative[0]=$line[29];

    #foreach $1 (<$infh>) {
    foreach $1 (@WTcall) {
        if (@WTcall eq $BadPosition){
            print "No_WT_Concensus\tNo_WT_Concensus\n";
        } elsif (@positive >= 0.6 && @negative >= 0.6){
            print "Methylated\tMethylated\n";
        } elsif (@positive <= 0.6 && @negative <= 0.6){
            print "Under-methylated\tUnder-methylated\n";
        } elsif(@positive >= 0.6 && @negative <=0.6){
            print "Hemimethylated (m6A)\tHemimethylated (A)\n";
        } elsif(@positive <= 0.6 && @negative >= 0.6){
            print "Hemimethylated (A)\tHemimethylated (m6A)\n";
        } else{
            print "Missing_Site\tMissing_Site\n";
        }
        #print "@WTcall\n$BadPosition\n";
        #print "@WTcall\t@positive\t@negative\n"
        #print "@negative\n";
    }
}

close $infh;
```

Sample Data:

```
Methylated  coding gene 619 thrA    NC_000913.3 pos 3   1   0.9535  1   NC_000913.3 619 +   18  0.8889  Methylated  coding gene 620 thrA    NC_000913.3 neg 3   0.9429  0.9756  0.9714  NC_000913.3 620 -   14  1
No_WT_Concensus coding gene 195410  ispU    NC_000913.3 pos 2   0.5789  0.766   0.6071  NC_000913.3 195410  +   39  0.5897  Methylated  coding gene 195411  ispU    NC_000913.3 neg 3   0.75    0.9074  0.9306  NC_000913.3 195411  -   21  0.8095
Under-methylated    pseudogene  3632965 yhiL    NC_000913.3 pos 0   0.0323  0.1429  0.0962  NC_000913.3 3632965 +   22  0.0909  Under-methylated    pseudogene  3632966 yhiL    NC_000913.3 neg 0   0.1463  0.175   0.1429  NC_000913.3 3632966 -   23  0
Methylated  intergenic  164636  hrpB-mrcB   NC_000913.3 pos 3   0.7381  0.7647  0.7273  NC_000913.3 164636  +   25  0.8 Methylated  intergenic  164637  hrpB-mrcB   NC_000913.3 neg 3   0.7 0.7931  0.7213  NC_000913.3 164637  -   25  0.4
Methylated  intergenic  269287  ykfA-perR   NC_000913.3 pos 3   0.875   0.8833  0.931   NC_000913.3 269287  +   22  0.8182  Methylated  intergenic  269288  ykfA-perR   NC_000913.3 neg 3   0.8077  0.6866  0.6491  NC_000913.3 269288  -   17  0.5294
Methylated  coding gene 4397856 mutL    NC_000913.3 pos 3   0.9245  0.9831  0.9661  blank   blank   blank   blank   blank   Methylated  coding gene 4397857 mutL    NC_000913.3 neg 3   0.9783  0.9808  0.9683  NC_000913.3 4397857 -   1   0
Methylated  coding gene 4397969 mutL    NC_000913.3 pos 3   0.9643  0.9524  1   blank   blank   blank   blank   blank   Methylated  coding gene 4397970 mutL    NC_000913.3 neg 3   1   1   1   blank   blank   blank   blank   blank
Methylated  coding gene 2761    thrA    NC_000913.3 pos 3   0.9259  0.8654  0.9242  NC_000913.3 2761    +   31  1   Methylated  coding gene 2762    thrA    NC_000913.3 neg 3   0.913   0.9636  0.9767  NC_000913.3 2762    -   29  0.9655
Methylated  coding gene 3073    thrB    NC_000913.3 pos 3   0.9677  0.8983  1   NC_000913.3 3073    +   29  1   Methylated  coding gene 3074    thrB    NC_000913.3 neg 3   1   0.9038  0.9778  NC_000913.3 3074    -   31  1
```

Comment: Do not use special variables like `$1` as loop variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables starting with the `@` sigil are arrays. When comparing an array, you're imposing a numeric scalar context on it, so it returns its size.

You don't need arrays for single values, just use scalars.

Don't use the special variable `$1` as a loop variable. It's confusing and cancels its special behaviour.

Here's how I'd rewrite your program. It still complains about comparing "blank" to a number, but I'm not sure what you want to do with those values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
die "Usage: $0 Filename\n" if @ARGV != 1;

my $file = shift;
my $BadPosition = 'No_WT_Concensus';

open my $infh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";

while (<$infh>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split /\t/;
    my ($wt_call, $positive, $negative) = @columns[0, 14, 29];

    if ($wt_call eq $BadPosition) {
        print "No_WT_Concensus\tNo_WT_Concensus\n";
    } elsif ($positive >= 0.6 && $negative >= 0.6) {
        print "Methylated\tMethylated\n";
    } elsif ($positive <= 0.6 && $negative <= 0.6) {
        print "Under-methylated\tUnder-methylated\n";
    } elsif ($positive >= 0.6 && $negative <=0.6) {
        print "Hemimethylated (m6A)\tHemimethylated (A)\n";
    } elsif ($positive <= 0.6 && $negative >= 0.6) {
        print "Hemimethylated (A)\tHemimethylated (m6A)\n";
    } else {
        print "Missing_Site\tMissing_Site\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note there's the small issue in the code where `$positive` and `$negative` both being 0.6 matches all branches, so ordering matters.

Comment: @briandfoy I used the same order as the original code. Also, that's why I haven't transformed it to a 2D dispatch table based on `$positive <=> 0.6` and `$negative <=> 0.6`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me try to dissect the issue w/ my code. Running this script on the sample data throws a lot of warnings & still doesn't parse the data correctly. This is the output: `Use of uninitialized value $positive in numeric ge (>=) at CallMethylation.New.pl line 18, <$infh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $positive in numeric lt (<) at CallMethylation.New.pl line 20, <$infh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $negative in numeric lt (<) at CallMethylation.New.pl line 20, <$infh> line 1.
Under-methylated Under-methylated` The first entry should be "Methylated\tMethylated\n'

Comment: When I run my script on your sample data, the first line returns `Methylated Methylated`. Are you sure you copied'n'pasted my code without a typo?

Comment: Also, I'm getting the following warnings: `Argument "blank" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at ./1.pl line 18` or `... line 20`. If you check the data, there's really "blank" in the column, but you didn't say what to do with such a value.

Comment: No, I see what is wrong. I recopied the test data I provided on this post and the tabs got switched to spaces. It works now. Thank you so much. For the 'blank's I was using them as a placeholder and hoping that they would get picked up by the final 'else statment' as "missing data". Will the final else statement have a problem with 'blank' being used as a placeholder?

Comment: Ok, to fix that I removed the final 'else statement', then I defined`my $Missing = "blank";` and added two 'elsif statements' after the first 'if statement'. Basically asking `elsif($negative eq $Missing) {print "Missing_Data\tMissingData\n";}`  as a placeholder and doing the same for `$negative`.

Comment: Yes, a string `'blank'` used in numeric context emits a warning, but it behaves as 0.

Answer (score 7):

Here are your requirements, edited to show parallel structure:

- X >= 0.6 and Y >= 0.6 then "ABC"
- X <  0.6 and Y <  0.6 then "CBA"
- X >= 0.6 but Y <  0.6 then "DEF"
- X <  0.6 but Y >= 0.6 then "FED"

Some of the requirements are `< 0.6`, but in your code you have `<= 0.6`.

You have two things to test and you should first look for a structure that tests each one only once. Here's so pseudocode that expresses that:

```
if X >= 0.6
    if Y >= 0.6
        "ABC"
    else
        "DEF"
else
    if Y >= 0.6
        "FED"
    else
        "CBA"
```

Once you know if a value is greater than or equal to a value, you also know if it is less than, so you don't have to test again. The test simply bifurcates; if you don't take one branch you must take the other.

Your code is a bit different because it matches both `$x >= 0.6` or `$x <= 0.6`, and the same for `$y`. This means that if both `$x` and `$y` are `0.6`, then any brnach can match and you'll get the first one in the chain. That seems like an error in the code because it's not what you described in the text.

### Get rid of the structure

I've had to do many projects that had long lists of these sorts of selections, many with hundreds of things to test.

Now, the trick is to turn that into Perl. Remember that a subroutine returns the last evaluated expression, so this works:

```
my @x_y = (
    [ 0.1, 0.7 ],
    [ 0.1, 0.1 ],
    [ 0.7, 0.1 ],
    [ 0.7, 0.7 ]
    );

foreach my $x_y ( @x_y ) {
    printf "X: %.1f Y: %.1f --> %s\n", @$x_y, get_value( @$x_y );
    }

sub get_value {
    my( $x, $y ) = @_;

    if( $x >= 0.6 ) { $y >= 0.6 ? 'ABC' : 'DEF' }
    else            { $y >= 0.6 ? 'FED' : 'CBA' }
    }
```

I might even go so far as to parameterize the pivot value and give it a value if I don't pass one:

```
sub get_value {
    my( $x, $y, $pivot ) = @_;
    $pivot //= 0.6;  # default value

    if( $x >= $pivot ) { $y >= $pivot ? 'ABC' : 'DEF' }
    else               { $y >= $pivot ? 'FED' : 'CBA' }
    }
```

With (experimental) subroutine signatures, that's a bit cleaner because I can set the default:

```
use v5.22;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

sub get_value ( $x, $y, $pivot = 0.6 ){
    if( $x >= $pivot ) { $y >= $pivot ? 'ABC' : 'DEF' }
    else               { $y >= $pivot ? 'FED' : 'CBA' }
    }
```

But things can get more interesting. I've repeated that test for `$y`, but I can save the result of a comparison:

```
use v5.22;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

sub get_value ( $x, $y, $pivot = 0.6 ){
    my $boolean = ($y >= $pivot);
    if( $x >= $pivot ) { $boolean ? 'ABC' : 'DEF' }
    else               { $boolean ? 'FED' : 'CBA' }
    }
```

But, what am I really doing here? I'm trying to select a value. I've represented this as a decision tree in code. What if I could flip that around? I can do the same saved result trick with `$x`:

```
use v5.22;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

sub get_value ( $x, $y, $pivot = 0.6 ){
    my $y_boolean = ($y >= $pivot);
    my $x_boolean = ($x >= $pivot);

    if( $x_boolean ) { $y_boolean ? 'ABC' : 'DEF' }
    else             { $y_boolean ? 'FED' : 'CBA' }
    }
```

So now I have a situation where I have the boolean combinations (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), and (1,1). I'll use those as array indices. The `state` makes a persistent varaible so I don't need to redefine it every time I call the subroutine. [Perl v5.28 allows you to initialize arrays and hashes in `state`](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2018/08/initialize-array-and-hash-variables-with-state/), and with earlier versions you just use a reference:

```
use v5.28;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

sub get_value ( $x, $y, $pivot = 0.6 ) {
    state @table = (
        [ qw(CBA FED) ],
        [ qw(DEF ABC) ]
        );

    my $y_boolean = ($y >= $pivot);
    my $x_boolean = ($x >= $pivot);

    $table[$x_boolean][$y_boolean];
    }
```

Or, slightly more compact, I can put the comparisons in the array indices:

```
use v5.28;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

sub get_value ( $x, $y, $pivot = 0.6 ){
    state @table = (
        [ qw(CBA FED) ],
        [ qw(DEF ABC) ]
        );
    $table[$x >= $pivot][$y >= $pivot];
    }
```

Now the values are separated from the mechanics—something I spend a lot of time on in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org). That can be a parameter too, although now it has to be an array ref because an array paramater cannot have a default value:

```
use v5.28;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

my @x_y = (
    [ 0.1, 0.7 ],
    [ 0.1, 0.1 ],
    [ 0.7, 0.1 ],
    [ 0.7, 0.7 ]
    );

my $pivot = 0.6;
my @table = ( [ qw(CBA FED) ], [ qw(DEF ABC) ] );

foreach my $x_y ( @x_y ) {
    printf "X: %.1f Y: %.1f --> %s\n", @$x_y,
        get_value( @$x_y, $pivot, \@table );
    }


sub get_value ( $x, $y, $pivot = 0.6,
    @table = ([ qw(DEF FED) ], [ qw(ABC CBA) ]) )
    {
    $table[$x >= $pivot][$y >= $pivot];
    }
```

This is much easier to manage. You can adjust the pivot and the values you get back while the mechanics don't change.

Going one step further takes the values out of the program completely and puts them in a configuration file. The same program can then handle many other situations without you having to edit it.

### For your case

Back to your code. [choroba shows you this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224420/2766176), which fixes some of the problems but leaves the `<=` issue in tact:

```
while (<$infh>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split /\t/;
    my ($wt_call, $positive, $negative) = @columns[0, 14, 29];

    if ($wt_call eq $BadPosition) {
        print "No_WT_Concensus\tNo_WT_Concensus\n";
    } elsif ($positive >= 0.6 && $negative >= 0.6) {
        print "Methylated\tMethylated\n";
    } elsif ($positive <= 0.6 && $negative <= 0.6) {
        print "Under-methylated\tUnder-methylated\n";
    } elsif ($positive >= 0.6 && $negative <=0.6) {
        print "Hemimethylated (m6A)\tHemimethylated (A)\n";
    } elsif ($positive <= 0.6 && $negative >= 0.6) {
        print "Hemimethylated (A)\tHemimethylated (m6A)\n";
    } else {
        print "Missing_Site\tMissing_Site\n";
    }
}
```

Cleaned up a bit, you have a `while` that controls the parts dealing with each line, and a subroutine that handles the parts for control the values.

```
use v5.28;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

while( <$infh> ) {
    chomp;
    my( $wt_call, $positive, $negative ) = (split /\t/)[0,14,29];
    if( $wt_call eq ... ) {
        print "No_WT_Concensus\tNo_WT_Concensus\n";
        next;
        }
    say get_value( $positive, $negative );
    }


sub get_value ( $x, $y, $pivot = 0.6 ){
    state @table = (
        [ qw(CBA FED) ],
        [ qw(DEF ABC) ]
        );
    $table[$x >= $pivot][$y >= $pivot];
    }
```

Note that the `else` condition is unreachable since you've covered all the cases already, so I omit that. If there's another situation where you want to look at empty fields (null versus 0), you'd capture that before `get_value`. One way is to look at the length of the field. If it's 0 (no characters), don't count it. You can have 0, 1, or 2 empty fields, and those might be different cases:

```
while( <$infh> ) {
    chomp;
    my( $wt_call, $positive, $negative ) = (split /\t/)[0,14,29];
    if( $wt_call eq ... ) {
        print "No_WT_Concensus\tNo_WT_Concensus\n";
        next;
        }
    # what if this is 1?
    unless( 2 == grep { length } ($positive, $negative) ) {
        print "No_WT_Concensus\tNo_WT_Concensus\n";
        next;
        }
    say get_value( $positive, $negative );
    }
```